# I cant get ExitNodes { } working

Tags: configuration, network-configuration

I've come across a bunch of posts covering this, with answers ranging from "update tor" to "this feature got removed"... and none of them helped me.

I run tor in alpine docker, installed from the alpine package manager.

I start tor like this... `tor -f /etc/tor/torrc`
...And my torrc looks like this...

```
ExitNodes {us}
StrictNodes 1
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: `StrictNodes` doesn't apply to `ExitNodes`. Why do you say that `ExitNodes` isn't working? How are you testing it?

Comment: OK. I only added `StrictNodes` because I read a user comment that said it was required. I am testing it by  curl-ing `ipinfo.io`. Sometimes I will be connected to a US exit, but a lot of the time I wont be.

Comment: Different geolocation databases might think that a relay is in different countries. You should get the exit relay's IP address and search for it here: https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search. That will tell you what country that Tor thinks the relay is in. They should all be US relays.

Comment: That's interesting. You are correct. Different sites believe the server is in different countries. It might not be a tor issue after all.